# Physical difference between retarded and advanced green's function in Electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, greens-functions

I do not fully understand the difference physically between a retarded solution and an advanced green's function solution to the wave equation with an arbitary source in electrodynamics. Can someone please explain to me the relation for each of these with respect to a fixed source?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/388468/physical-difference-between-retarded-and-advanced-greens-function-in-electrodyn

Answer (score 4):

In one dimension the advanced solution would propagate in the +x direction and the retarded solution in the -x direction.  In three dimensions the advanced solution would be an expanding spherical wave and the retarded solution a contracting spherical wave (until it reaches the center of the sphere).

Comment: I think I have swapped 'retarded' and 'advanced' here--sorry-the nomenclature is confusing. See Gilbert's answer.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the previous answer, the retarded solutions can be considered as propagating forward in time, while the advanced solutions travel backward in time. Thus, the retarded solutions originate from a source *retarded* in the past, and the advanced solutions originate from a source *advanced* in the future.

Comment: So basically the for the retarded solution, we are looking for the solution of a source which gave out radiation in the past? while for adv, we are looking at the solution of a source which is in future? if so, then how is adv solution physically realisable?

Comment: @seaofpoppies The advanced solution isn’t so much physically realizable as it is a mathematical tool, as far as I know. Of course, there other ways it creeps into physical theories as well. E.g. check out Wheeler-Feynman absorber theory.